# Facebook Comment Box

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can't seem to find out how to make the Facebook comment box work probably.

I have now setup the site with this code.

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '272xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/da_DK/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

and with theese META parameters

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="27xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="random title"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="10my_fb_id100"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="testapp"/>
```

I cannot moderate any comments that's made.

Also, I tested the comment box by typing in random comments, and then deleting them afterwards. They are not deleted in the counting though. How can I fix that?

Thanks for your time to help me,
Marcus.

Comment: Step 1: Validate your OG meta implementation using the debug tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: We have just launched a new comments plugin with new a new [moderation tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/114234242027487/). If you are facing such issues in the new tool as well, then feel free to [create a bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/).